# Get the list of commits from SVN repository and display it in own application

Tags: c#, .net, svn, svn-api

I need to implement the application that retrieve the list of commits from SVN repository and displays them on web page.

How can I do it ?

I'm not understand very good what should I use. It seems it can be done using some SVN api or library...

(The application in .NET)

Comment: [SharpSvn](https://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/)

Comment: @Patrick Quirk okey, but I can't still find how to retrieve all revisions using this lib (managed to retrieve only last revision)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a nifty function that I use to execute SVN commands from a .NET environment:

```
// execute a SVN command and fetch the output as a string
private string ExecuteSVNCommandWithOutput(string SVNCommand)
{
    string output = "";

    try
    {
        using (Process p = new Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + SVNCommand;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; 
            p.Start();

            output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    // unexpected error
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        output = ex.ToString();
    }

    return output;
}
```

For your purposes, I would do the following to run an `svn log`:

```
ExecuteSVNCommandWithOutput(@"svn log C:\Repositories\YourRepositoryName");
```

You could then parse the string output into an Array or a List of some sort. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can call svn log (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html) from the command line (or using the Process class), redirect the output to a file and then open and parse the file.

Parsing the default text output is not hard, but with the --xml option, the file can be parsed more easily with any XML library.